# Meaning of `authenticationMethod` and `authenticationInstant` in "Post Recipient View"

Tags: docusignapi

According to the API docs for ["Post Recipient View"](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Post%20Recipient%20View.htm), the attributes mean:

> authenticationMethod: A sender created value that indicates the convention used to authenticate the signer. This information is included in the Certificate of Completion.
>
> authenticationInstant: A sender generation[sic] value that indicates the date/time that the signer was authenticated.

I'm not sure what is meant by "the convention used to authenticate the signer". My users are authenticated via Email/Password, as is fairly common. What are the valid values for these attributes (`"EmailWithPassword"` was not accepted by the API)? What value corresponds to "authentication via password"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The authenticationMethod is a required field/metadata that is added to the Certificate of Completion. It is in your best interest to supply a value that best describes how your application authenticated the signer so you have an accurate replay/history when reviewing the certificate of completion. Accepted values listed below:

- "Password"
- "Email"
- "PaperDocuments"
- "HTTPBasicAuth"
- "SSLMutualAuth"
- "X509Certificate"
- "Kerberos"
- "SingleSignOn_CASiteminder"
- "SingleSignOn_InfoCard"
- "SingleSignOn_MicrosoftActiveDirectory"
- "SingleSignOn_Passport"
- "SingleSignOn_SAML"
- "SingleSignOn_Other"
- "Smartcard"
- "RSASecureID"
- "Biometric"
- "None"
- "KnowledgeBasedAuth"

Comment: Awesome! Do you have a source for this? Not that I don't believe you; I just want to know what I missed in my research.

Comment: : ) understood. I grabbed it from one of the API schemas: https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/schema/dsx.xsd

Comment: Note that "Email" in this case means you validated their email address (similar to normal DocuSign emails) whereas "Password" is what you'd use in this case.